# Using Apache Flink for data streaming

Tags: apache-flink, flink-streaming

I am working on building an application with below requirements and I am just getting started with flink.

- Ingest data into Kafka with say 50 partitions (Incoming rate - 100,000 msgs/sec)
- Read data from Kafka and process each data (Do some computation, compare with old data etc) real time
- Store the output on Cassandra

I was looking for a real time streaming platform and found Flink to be a great fit for both real time and batch.

- Do you think flink is the best fit for my use case or should I use Storm, Spark streaming or any other streaming platforms?
- Do I need to write a data pipeline in google data flow to execute my sequence of steps on flink or is there any other way to perform a sequence of steps for realtime streaming?
- Say if my each computation take like 20 milliseconds, how can I better design it with flink and get better throughput.
- Can I use Redis or Cassandra to get some data within flink for each computation?
- Will I be able to use JVM in-memory cache inside flink?
- Also can I aggregate data based on a key for some time window (example 5 seconds). For example lets say there are 100 messages coming in and 10 messages have the same key, can I group all messages with the same key together and process it.
- Are there any tutorials on best practices using flink?

Thanks and appreciate all your help.

Answer (score 3):

Given your task description, Apache Flink looks like a good fit for your use case.

In general, Flink provides [low latency and high throughput](http://data-artisans.com/high-throughput-low-latency-and-exactly-once-stream-processing-with-apache-flink/) and has a parameter to tune these. You can read and write data from and to Redis or Cassandra. However, you can also [store state internally in Flink](http://data-artisans.com/extending-the-yahoo-streaming-benchmark/). Flink does also have [sophisticated support for windows](http://flink.apache.org/news/2015/12/04/Introducing-windows.html). You can read the [blog on the Flink website](http://flink.apache.org/blog/), check out the [documentation](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-release-1.0/) for more information, or follow this [Flink training](http://dataartisans.github.io/flink-training/) to learn the API.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I would like to get one more thing clarified. Should I be using google dataflow sdk for creating a pipeline and run it on flink or does flink itself have some sdk in which I can create a pipeline. I looked at the data stream api but wasn't quite able to figure out if it has all the functionalities similar to dataflow. Thanks for your help.

Comment: The Apache Beam (formerly Google DataFlow API) runner is implemented on top of Flink's DataStream API. So the DataStream API is (at least) as expressive as the Beam API.