# Can Redis Streams be used as source for Flink

Tags: redis, apache-flink, flink-streaming, redis-streams

I am new to Flink and going through documentation. I found out that Redis can be used as SINK (through Apache Bahir). But there is no mention of using Redis Streams as source, for streaming data. Is it possible to add Redis stream as source to Flink?

I tried googling it but could not find any answers. If this question is already asked please provide the link as i am not able to find it.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Read data from Redis to Flink](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44193182/read-data-from-redis-to-flink)

Comment: @DavidAnderson Thankyou for the link. I went through it and found out that the ticket is still in open status for adding redis streams as source to Flink : [link](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/FLINK-3033) FLINK3033. Checked in apache Bahir as well, no sign of redis streams even now. So i think i have to settle with Kafka ,unless there is a way to link redis streams as source to Flink

Comment: That's right, unless you are willing to write your own, as described here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/44294980/2000823